# Nutrition and Diet tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Should the [nutrition](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) and [diet](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) tags be merged? They seem to be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, I think [diet](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) should be merged into [nutrition](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) and set as a synonym.

Update: and now it is done.

Comment: Yes, the consensus is pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

Neither tag has a description, so it's not surprising they get used inaccurately.

I would have thought they were different, but if we cannot define them to be substantially different, then yes, they should be merged.

Suggested definitions (improvements invited)

**Diet** [definitions](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Diet&ls=a) applicable to cycling would be

- *the kind and amount of food prescribed for a person for a special reason (health, weight, performance, etc)*

**Nutrition** [definitions](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Nutrition&ls=a) can be distinguished from diet as

- *The science that deals with nutrients and nutrition*